# Setting a window to full screen programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to resize a console window to full screen in a non-.NET C++ application that runs under Windows 10.

I am able to get rid of the window frame and resize, using one of `SetWindowPos` or `MoveWindow` from the WinAPI.

But the window origin (top-left corner) does not move to the top-left corner of the screen and stays in its initial position, which is random. In fact, the `X`, `Y` arguments of these functions seem to be just ignored.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: hey, that's becoming better and close to my need ! Strangely, a scroll bar appears on the right, and clearing the WS_VSCROLL bit in the window style does not work :-(

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: now done (I needed to reduce the buffer size of the console). If you want you can enter your suggestion as an answer. Otherwise I'll do it.

Comment: No, you go ahead.

Comment: Same as `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);`, but you may want to check [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) (SetConsoleMode + `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` enables VT100 compatible mode, the suggested behavior - cross-platform compat).

Comment: @Jimi: you are right, works too. Regarding the VT100 mode, though I loved that terminal in another life and have been looking for this emulation for a while, this is not at all my purpose here.

Comment: Sure. But you can also set the Window size using escape sequences. -  Just a note, since, as you can read in the Docs, the standard methods as `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize`, `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` & Co. are kind of *deprecated* (not exactly, but for compat reasons, following the new behavior is *suggested* almost everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

That did it:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
```

Adjust the buffer and window sizes of the console to avoid scrollbars.

Credit to
500 - Internal Server Error
.